# c# Converter from html to pdf, xls

Tags: asp.net, html, pdf-generation, converters, xls

Hi i'm looking for a free asp.net library for converting html in pdf, xls formats?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about ITextSharp?

http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html

That might help.

Certainly does XHtml to PDF
http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch07.html

Comment: Or maybe this may help? http://www.primopdf.com/index.aspx

For xls format try looking at this answer. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891531/convert-xls-doc-files-to-pdf-with-c

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ABCpdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-html.htm)...

It's a PDF library designed for use with ASP.NET.  Imports web pages and HTML, and office document formats such as XLS.

ABCpdf is a commercial product, however the standard edition can be obtained free of charge as a special offer.

Answer (score 0):

I know you stated that it should be free but try

[winnovative](http://www.winnovative-software.com/?gclid=CLqd3I3ixp8CFcpb4wodNHnJzg)

They have a free trial. Its pretty awesome.